Validate typescript union type on runtime
Context:
type NonFeline = 'Mouse' | 'Sheep';
type Feline = 'Lion' | 'Cat' ;

type AnimalInfo = {
    Category: NonFeline;
    Age: number;
} | {
   Category: Feline;
   Age: number;   
   Owner:string;
};

let x: AnimalInfo = getAnimal(1);
if(x.Category === 'Lion' || x.Category === 'Cat'){
  console.log(x.Owner);
}

function getAnimal(i: number): AnimalInfo{
  return i % 2 ? {
    Category: "Lion",
    Age: 10,
    Owner: "Y"
  } : {
    Category: "Mouse",
    Age: 1,
  };
}

How can I be sure when later I added "Tiger" to Animal type, no need to change to if, or at least if gives me a compile time typescript error?

In your question you request help for a validation on runtime but Typescript does not run, it compiles to JavaScript first, and then the resulting JS is what executes. TS is designed to catch issues at compilation, not at runtime.

To solve the runtime check use a set, extract values from it as a type and use a type predicate function (Set#has() doesn't narrow unfortunately) to check whether AnimalInfo is Feline:
Playground
type SetValues<T extends Set<unknown>> = T extends Set<infer I> ? I : never;

const felineCategories = new Set(['Lion', 'Cat'] as const); // you add any new types here
const isFeline = (animal: AnimalInfo): animal is Feline => felineCategories.has(animal.Category as FelineCategory);
type FelineCategory = SetValues<typeof felineCategories>;
type AnimalCategory = 'Mouse' | 'Sheep';

type Animal = {
    Category: AnimalCategory;
    Age: number;
}

type Feline = {
   Category: FelineCategory;
   Age: number;   
   Owner:string;
}

type AnimalInfo = Animal | Feline;

declare const x: AnimalInfo;
if(isFeline(x)){
  console.log(x.Owner);
}

An array version:
Playground
const felineCategories = ['Lion', 'Cat'] as const; // you add any new types here
const isFeline = (animal: AnimalInfo): animal is Feline => felineCategories.includes(animal.Category as FelineCategory);
type FelineCategory = typeof felineCategories[number];
type AnimalCategory = 'Mouse' | 'Sheep';

type Animal = {
    Category: AnimalCategory;
    Age: number;
}

type Feline = {
   Category: FelineCategory;
   Age: number;   
   Owner:string;
}

type AnimalInfo = Animal | Feline;

declare const x: AnimalInfo;
if(isFeline(x)){
  console.log(x.Owner);
}


Thanks, it seems using "type predicate function" is inevitable.

@mehran i'm dissappointed that TS CANNOT narrow by Set#has() or Array#includes(), moreover the methods can accept any strings by TS allows only values in the set or array which lame and alogical so a type cast is needed
